# Custom UITableViewCell not responding to changes

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I've created a custom `UItableViewCell`. I've put a Label into the cell in storyboard and made the connection to the class. I want to change the position of the label depending on the row index. This is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

// Configure the cell...

cell.titleLabel.frame = CGRectMake(100.0, 20.0, cell.titleLabel.frame.size.width, cell.titleLabel.frame.size.height);

cell.titleLabel.text = @"Test";

return cell;
```

}

The problem is that the label does not change position, its on the same place where I put it in storyboard. However, when I scroll up and down, the cells are loaded again and the label move to the right place. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Uhm, if you connected the IBOutlet it would works. This method sounds new to me dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath: ? Why index path ? Also, have you tried to implement prepareForReuse: in your custom cell ?

Comment: Leo, this is a usual method to deque a reusable cell :) But when you load the table for the first time there are no cells to dequeue, so it seems that it is the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you actually forgot to create a cell (at least I do not see the code which creates the cell). This might looks smth like:

```
SPAccountHeaderCell * headerCell = (SPAccountHeaderCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"headerCell"];
if (headerCell == nil) {
     headerCell = [[SPAccountHeaderCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"headerCell"];
}
```